# How do I change x-axis from numeric to custom ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like:

```
require(ggplot2); require(lubridate); require(data.table); require(dplyr)

Date  <- rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "days"), 3)
Index <- rep(c(rep(1:365, times = 2), 1:366), 3)
Counts<- sample(1:25, size = length(Index), replace = TRUE)
City  <- rep(c("Dallas", "San Antonio", "Houston"), each = length(Index)/3)

df    <- data.frame(Date = Date, Index = Index, Counts = Counts, City = City)

df    <- df %>% mutate(Year = year(as.Date(Date)))
```

I graphed the data using the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Index, y = Counts, colour = City)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = City))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(31, 59.5, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334))+
  facet_grid(Year~.) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

My goal is to actually label the x-axis as *Jan Feb ... Dec*. I have tried `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_x_discrete` with no avail. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is easier to achieve if you use `Date` as your `x` variable and make use of `scale_x_date`:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Year = year(as.Date(Date)),
                    MonthStart = round_date(Date, unit = "month"))

mid_months <- seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-15"), as.Date("2016-12-15"), by = "months")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Counts, colour = City)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = City))+
    facet_wrap(~ Year, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = MonthStart), colour = 'black') +
    # expand = c(0,0) to ensure scale doesn't extend to additional
    #   months
    scale_x_date(breaks = mid_months, date_labels = "%b", expand = c(0, 0)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

EDIT: updated to add mid-month labels

[image: dateplot]

Comment: is there any way to center the labels and remove the last "Jan"?

Comment: I tried using the `limits` portion of `scale_x_date` and couldn't figure it out?

Comment: how do I improve your code to show what I was looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A quick option to make use of what you've already got is to pass your vector of x intercepts to `scale_x_continuous` as breaks, and use `month.abb` to name them:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
    Date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "days"), 3),
    Index = rep(c(rep(1:365, times = 2), 1:366), 3),
    Counts = sample(1:25, size = length(Index), replace = TRUE),
    City = rep(c("Dallas", "San Antonio", "Houston"), each = length(Index) / 3),
    Year = lubridate::year(Date)
)

month_breaks <- c(31, 59.5, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Index, y = Counts, colour = City)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = month_breaks) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = month_breaks, labels = month.abb[-1]) +
    facet_grid(Year ~ .) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]